# AWS migrate regions and instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently on Oregon (west-2) t1.micro free. I want to migrate my instance from there to Sydney and also upgrade to a small instance.

My problems:
Sydney has no t1.small instances, just t2.small
Secondly, the t2 instance doesn't support PV, which my old t1 instance was (just HVM)
I've managed to copy across a snapshot of the instance to my region but whenever I try to launch I can't SSH and the machine shuts down with reason: "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown".
I've read some stuff about choosing the right kernel but have no idea what any of it means or how I'd figure out the right one, is it even relevant to me, could this be my problem.

Any idea how I can debug what's going on?
Any guidance on step by step what I actually need to do to get my t1.micro Ubuntu (PV) snapshot working on a t2.small Ubuntu (HVM) in a different region.

Can this be done, this is all quite confusing and stressful; I'm a developer, not dev ops, but trying to learn and figure things out.

Comment: what is the o/p you get when you right click the aws instance on the website and check logs

Comment: I don't understand your question. I tried launching AMI `ami-04ea7a3e` (Ubuntu 12_04) in Sydney and it does show me that it has `t1.micro` size as well as it is `PV`. The AMI that you are using, is it a custom AMI ? Which Operating System are you on ? any other information with respect to AMI/Instance would be helpful. Don't reply in Comments, Instead, Update your post with additional information.

Answer (score -1):

Hoping this helps you, i was able to do it when i needed to move some servers from Virginia to Oregon

http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/moving-ec2-instances-across-availability-zones-or-aws-regions.html

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't with the migration itself. AWS provide UI features for this now. I have the image and snapshot in my region. I just can't create instances that boot from them. I guess because I've had to switch to t2 from t1 and HVM from PV.